# how can I control cmake's portion of the install path

Tags: installation, cmake, cross-compiling

I'm using cmake to generate Makefiles on an x86_64 RHEL5 Linux box. cmake's generated "install" target installs to a path that is partially controllable (with DESTDIR and CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX) and partly fixed. What kind of controls do I have over the fixed portion, e.g.:

```
myproject-1.2.0/rhel_5/gcc-4.3.3/i386/release/lib/libmyproject.so.1.2.0
                ^^^^^^           ^^^^
```

I ask because I'm actually cross-compiling to an arm platform using a gnu 4.3.3 compiler, so that portion is correct. But the toolchain file doesn't seem to contain variables to affect the "rhel_5" and "i386" parts.

My arm cross-compiler has march=armv4t listed when I dump its specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have full control over the fixed portion.  From the [docs for `install`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3ainstall):

> `DESTINATION` arguments specify the directory on disk to which a file will be installed. If a full path (with a leading slash or drive letter) is given it is used directly. If a relative path is given it is interpreted relative to the value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. The prefix can be relocated at install time using `DESTDIR` mechanism explained in the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable documentation.

So the "fixed" portion is the path specified in the `install` command(s) as the `DESTINATION` argument in your CMakeLists.txt file(s).

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's that easy. I was being mislead by some helper code, mistaking it's actions for built-in behavior.